# Presenting Navigation Controller within Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My application has a tab bar controller with two controllers embed - a navigation bar and a view controller.

We'll call the View Controller **Number Pad** and the Navigation bar and its root view controller **Display**.

I have a button in **Number Pad** that takes in input from a textfield and displays the corresponding information in a label on **Display**.

This is my code for the button:

```
SongController *songMain = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SongDisplay"];

UINavigationController *navigate = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:songMain];

[self presentViewController:navigate animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I used this method the tabBar on **Display** is missing.
Is there anyway to still have both the tab bar and Navigation Controller at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're trying to do this is wrong. The navigation controller already exists (as one of the tab bar controller's view controllers) so you don't want to instantiate it again, or present it. What you want to do is change the selectedIndex parameter of the tab view controller to switch to that view:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Yes I tried this method already. The problem is that with this button i'm also passing the value from the text field and displaying it in the label of the another view controller. When I use your method the label does not change.

Comment: @KyleRoach, well that's not going to happen without you telling it to do so -- my answer was to your question which is about how to have both the tab bar and navigation controller at the same time. To pass the value, you should probably use delegation (but that's another question entirely).